# A simple regular expression

Tags: regex

I am not familiar with regular expression.

For a string, I want to replace all the non-letter and non-digit characters with space, and then merge the spaces so that there is no two consecutive spaces.

How to achieve that using regular expression?

Comment: Do you have to use a regular expression for this? It could be done without them and probably easier to understand...

Comment: Sterling, I doubt a non-regex version would be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two replacements:

1. Replace `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` by a space
2. Replace `[ ]{2,}` by a single space (the character class is only needed here because SO's parser messes up – usually a space suffices on its own)

In PowerShell that'd look like

```
$s -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ' -replace ' {2,}', ' '
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need 2 passes

replace

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

with 1 space

replace

```
[ ]{2,}
```

With 1 space

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need yourself a

```
replace(mystring, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
```

Comment: Isn't `\a` resembles a `bell character`? Quite misleading!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about doing this with a single regex, but two seems to do the trick

```bash
 echo -n 'dog*&$\@$ cat   On1 tw0' |
     perl -pe 's/([^([:alnum:])]|\s)/ /g' |
         perl -pe 's/\s+/ /g'
```

**Output** = `dog cat On1 tw0`